# How to make own maven repository and dependency for open source?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, repository, maven-3

I want to make my own Repository for access it from anywhere using Maven. 
 just like i wanted to write my own group Id,artifact ID and version inside any pom.xml in any project and dependency should be downloaded.

Comment: I think you need nexus https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-sonatype

Comment: What exactly do you want? If you want to publish open source components, you should probably publish them to MavenCentral. If you want to run your own public Maven repository, you need to have a publicly available server and put a Nexus or Artifactory on it. Nevertheless, Maven will only recognise this server if the Maven user lists it in their `settings.xml`.

Comment: yes exactly..i want to publish open source on Maven Central.but i couldn't find out how to do this?and sorry but i am developer is there any free server to host my repo?..thanks in advance..

Comment: Hi, if you like to publish to Central which is documented here: https://central.sonatype.org/ and than your artifacts are offered there. You don't need your own server ....

Comment: You can try jitpack.io or build your own artifactory via JFrog dockers.